# Single pool vs multipool mining?

Tags: mining-pools

I noted that many clients now-a-days have the option for multipool. Regarding such feature I've got two questions:

What are the advantages of being in a multipool setup against the single pool?

Is such setup option fair for those people who are in only one pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multipool clients generally have two sets of functionality fail-over or load balancing.  Fail-over is simply having backup servers in place so that your miner can continue working if your primary server goes down or experiences a connectivity issue.  Load balancing will split up the work across multiple pools simultaneously.  This would make the most sense to me in an environment where multiple people purchase a rather expensive mining rig and want to distribute shares of the rigs capability to accounts that are controlled by different owners.  I can't see a scenario where this functionality could be unfair to someone mining in a single pool.